# Group by variables to create new table

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

The first table is the data at hand and I am looking to create table-2 using it.
In the second table, comment type is the important variable that needs to be created. It is created using first table. Grouped by user and video we need to identify if a sad comment was made first or a happy comment was made first (from column Happy in first table. Yes means the comment was happy and no means the comment was sad). If a happy comment was made first before sad comment in a video by the user then comment_type in second table is coded as Happy. If a sad comment is made first before happy comment the comment type in table 2 is Sad. If only one type of comment exists for a unique user in a unique video (either happy or sad as is the case with user a in V2 and V3 or user b in V1) it is coded as None.

| User | Video | Comment | Happy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | V1 | 1 | No |
| a | V1 | 2 | Yes |
| a | V1 | 3 | No |
| a | V2 | 4 | Yes |
| a | V3 | 5 | No |
| a | V3 | 6 | No |
| a | V4 | 7 | Yes |
| a | V4 | 8 | No |
| a | V4 | 9 | No |
| b | V1 | 10 | No |
| b | V1 | 11 | No |
| b | V5 | 12 | Yes |
| b | V5 | 13 | Yes |
| b | V5 | 14 | No |

```
df <- tibble(
  User = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
  Video = c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V3", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V1", "V1", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5"),
  Comment = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
  Happy = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"))
```

| User | Video | Comment_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | V1 | Sad |
| a | V2 | None |
| a | V3 | None |
| a | V4 | Happy |
| b | V1 | None |
| b | V5 | Happy |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very straightforward with [case_when](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html):

```
df |>
  dplyr::summarise(`Comment Type` = dplyr::case_when(
    length(unique(Happy)) == 1 ~ "None",
    first(Happy)  == "Yes" ~ "Happy",
    first(Happy)  == "No" ~ "Sad"), .by = c(User, Video))
```

Notes:

1. Using "Yes" and "No" for TRUE and FALSE is bad practice- it takes up more space, is slower, and requires longer code. Something to change going forward
2. You could replace `length(unique(Happy)) == 1` with `n_distinct(Happy) == 1`, as in Jon Spring's deleted answer (credit to them).

Comment: I didn't even know about the command 'first'. This worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: it's the same as `Happy[1]`